# How to define Eq instance of List without GADTs or Datatype Contexts

Tags: list, haskell, compiler-flags, algebraic-data-types, gadt

I am using `Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.8.3, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.6.3`.

I attempted to use the following data definition for a List type in Haskell:

```
data Eq a => List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

However, the `-XDatatypeContexts` flag is required, depricated, and even removed from the language by default. It is widely viewed as a misfeature of the language. I also do not want to have to use special flags for my definition of List since I am trying to replicate the functionality of the existing list type.
Then I was able to use the following segment of code instead:

```
data List a where
 Nil :: List a
 Cons :: Eq a => a -> List a -> List a
```

It runs fine. The visible issue with this solution is that now I need to use the `-XGADTs` flag, which I still don't want to depend on in this case since it is not necessary for the built in version of list to function. Is there a way to restrict the type within `Cons` to be `Eq a` so that I can compare two lists without the need for compiler flags and without using the `derived` keyword?
The remaining code is as follows:

```
instance Eq (List a) where
 (Cons a b) == (Cons c d) = (a == c) && (b == d)
 Nil == Nil = True
 _ == _ = False
testfunction = Nil :: List Int
main = print (if testfunction == Nil then "printed" else "not printed")
```

I see that the following solution works:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
instance Eq a => Eq (List a) where
 (Cons a b) == (Cons c d) = (a == c) && (b == d)
 Nil == Nil = True
 _ == _ = False
testfunction = Nil :: List Int
main = print (if testfunction == Nil then "printed" else "not printed")
```

However, for some reason, it does not work with a manual definition for Eq (Equals here).

```
class Equal a where  
 (=+=) :: a -> a -> Bool  
 (/+=) :: a -> a -> Bool  
 x =+= y = not (x /+= y)  
 x /+= y = not (x =+= y)
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
instance Equal a => Equal (List a) where
 (Cons a b) =+= (Cons c d) = (a =+= c) && (b =+= d)
 Nil =+= Nil = True
 _ =+= _ = False
testfunction = Nil :: List Int
main = print (if testfunction =+= Nil then "printed" else "not printed")
```

I get the following error:

```
No instance for (Equal Int) arising from a use of ‘=+=’
    In the expression: testfunction =+= Nil
    In the first argument of ‘print’, namely
      ‘(if testfunction =+= Nil then "printed" else "not printed")’
    In the expression:
      print (if testfunction =+= Nil then "printed" else "not printed")
```

However, by using GADT's, I can show that my Equal class does actually function. This code works:

```
class Equal a where  
 (=+=) :: a -> a -> Bool  
 (/+=) :: a -> a -> Bool  
 x =+= y = not (x /+= y)  
 x /+= y = not (x =+= y)
data List a where
 Nil :: List a
 Cons :: Equal a => a -> List a -> List a
instance Equal (List a) where
 (Cons a b) =+= (Cons c d) = (a =+= c) && (b =+= d)
 Nil =+= Nil = True
 _ =+= _ = False
testfunction = Nil :: List Int
main = print (if testfunction =+= Nil then "printed" else "not printed")
```

However, I have to use `instance Equal (List a) where` instead of `instance Equal a => Equal (List a) where` otherwise I get the error:

```
No instance for (Equal Int) arising from a use of ‘=+=’
    In the expression: testfunction =+= Nil
    In the first argument of ‘print’, namely
      ‘(if testfunction =+= Nil then "printed" else "not printed")’
    In the expression:
      print (if testfunction =+= Nil then "printed" else "not printed")
```

Comment: The "no instance for `Equal Int`" error you are getting is because there is no instance for `Equal Int`  :-P.  You have to define it: `instance Equal Int where ...`  (It's actually pretty rare that the correct solution to "no instance" errors is to define an instance, but in this case it is)

Comment: Also I observe that your GADT studies might be getting in the way of a good understanding of typeclasses, a fundamental feature of the language.  I suggest taking a step back from GADTs until you are proficient with typeclasses, and perhaps study the [prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/Prelude.html) and how its classes and instances are defined.

Comment: Oops that's a terrible prelude link. Try [the one from the report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html)

Comment: Try actually using `Cons 1 Nil :: List Int`, instead of just `Nil :: List Int`; you'll *still* get an error about `No instance for (Equal Int)`. The problem is that you haven't defined how you can use `Int` with `=+=` before trying to use `List Int` with `=+=`; this has nothing to do with whether you use the GADT approach or the constraint-on-the-instance approach. The GADT approach **does not** remove the burden of proving that the elements in the list can be compared for equality, it just *moves* the burden of proof from the use sites of `==` to the construction sites of your lists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to restrict lists to only be able to hold values that implement `Eq`, and you can't do that without extensions.  You can, however, tell the compiler how to compare two `List a`s when `a` has a type that implements `Eq`.  There are two easy ways to do this.  The simplest is with a deriving statement:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving (Eq)
```

Or you can define it manually:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (List a) where
    (Cons a b) == (Const c d) = (a == c) && (b == d)
    Nil == Nil = True
    _ == _ = False
```

Now whenever you fill your `List` type with something that implements `Eq`, the list will also be comparable using `==`.  There's no need to restrict the values that can be inside `Cons`.  You can certainly have a normal list of functions, like

```
fs1 :: [Int -> Int]
fs1 = [(+1), (*3), (+2), (*4)]
```

Or in your case

```
fs2 :: List (Int -> Int)
fs2 = Cons (+1) $ Cons (*3) $ Cons (+2) $ Cons (*4) Nil
```

Which can be used as

```
> map ($ 10) fs1
[11, 30, 12, 40]
```

And given

```
map' :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
map' f Nil = Nil
map' f (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) (map' f xs)
```

Then

```
> map' ($ 10) fs2
Cons 11 (Cons 30 (Cons 12 (Cons 40 Nil)))
```

Although to actually view it in GHCi you should also derive `Show`:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving (Eq, Show)
```

There are several other useful typeclasses that can be derived in GHC, too.

---

To make it work with your custom `Equal` typeclass, you'll have to write multiple instances by hand:

```
class Equal a where
    (=+=) :: a -> a -> Bool
    (/+=) :: a -> a -> Bool
    x =+= y = not (x /+= y)
    x /+= y = not (x =+= y)

instance Equal Int where
    x =+= y = x == y

instance Equal a => Equal (List a) where
    (Cons a b) =+= (Cons c d) = (a =+= c) && (b =+= d)
    Nil =+= Nil = True
    _ =+= _ = False
```

Now because you have an instance `Equal Int` and `Equal a => Equal (List a)`, you can compare two `List Int`s:

```
> let x = Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Nil)) :: List Int
> let y = Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Nil)) :: List Int
> x =+= y
True
> x =+= Nil
False
```

For whatever type you want to store in a `List` and use `=+=` on, you'll have to implement `Equal` for that type.

Comment: Currently, your answer appears to only work for the Eq class built into Haskell. However, I need a solution that works for any class. I am updating the question accordingly.

Comment: @TimothySwan No. The deriving part only works with a handful of builtin classes, but manually defining instances always works.

Comment: @Cubic Yes. I know. I just updated my question to show how manually defining the instance with my own definition of Eq still didn't work the same in the case without the compiler flags.

Comment: @bheklilr I understand why the custom Equal class did not work. I needed to define the equality to work for Int type since I was using those in the actual expressions.

Answer (score 3):

The usual solution to this is to to use this structure:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

instance Eq a => Eq (List a) where
 (Cons a b) == (Cons c d) = (a == c) && (b == d)
 Nil == Nil = True
 _ == _ = False
```

Noticed I've added `Eq a` as a constraint to the *instance*, not to the data type. This way all the lists that you could compare for equality the way you're trying to write it can be compared for equality, but you also allow the existence of lists of things which cannot be compared for equality. And this is supported by every version of Haskell you will encounter, even very old ones, with no extensions.

This approach then also extends nicely when you want to add a `Show` instance, an `Ord` instance, etc; to do it your way you have to keep going back and making the data structure more restrictive by adding more constraints (potentially breaking existing code that worked fine because it didn't need those instances). Whereas if you leave the data type unconstrained and just make your instances `Show a => Show (List a)`, `Ord a => Ord (List a)`, etc, then you can show *and* order lists of types which happen to support both, but you can still have (and show) lists of types that support `Show` but not `Ord` and vice versa.

Plus, there are lots of useful type classes for parameterised types (such as `List a`) that *require* them to be fully generic in their type parameter. Examples are `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad`; it is not possible to correctly implement these for the constrained list type you're trying to create.

While it *is* possible to create constrained lists like you're trying to (but only by using extensions, as you've found), it has been found to be usually much more useful to leave your data types fully generic in their type parameter, and if a particular usage of your type needs to impose restrictions on the type parameter you impose them *at that usage site*, not at **every** use of the data type. This should be your "default setting"; depart from it when you have a good reason (you may well have such a reason here, but you haven't given it to us in the question, so nobody can recommend the best way of handling it).

Comment: It appears as though this solution works as long as I actually use the built in Eq class. Strangely, a custom built Eq class, which otherwise works, does not work with this solution. I defined one as follows:
class Equal a where  
    (=+=) :: a -> a -> Bool  
    (/+=) :: a -> a -> Bool  
    x =+= y = not (x /+= y)  
    x /+= y = not (x =+= y)

Comment: @TimothySwan, there is nothing special about the built-in `Eq` class except that it has a bunch of defined instances for built-in types. You should be able to emulate it completely, including with this solution (which is the standard solution to your problem and I have done it many times)